# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined when Adding GetJson on Initialize()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps-api-3

I am new to Google maps and i have an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined` Can someone tell me what is the problem with my code. .

The error is pointing

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
                if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;
```

and

```
window.onload = function () {
            initialize();
            codeAddress();
        }
```

This is the Code in my Initialize()

```
var geocoder, infoBubble;
        var map;
        //var mgr;

        function initialize() {
            var minZoomLevel = 4;
            var zooms = 7;
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            $.getJSON('/Dashboard/LoadAddress', function Geocode(address) {
                $.each(address, function () {
                    var currValAddress = this["AddressLine1"];
                    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': currValAddress }, function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                                zoom: minZoomLevel,
                                center: currValAddress,
                                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                            })
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                        }
                    })
                });
            });

            // Bounds for North America
            var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
     new google.maps.LatLng(15.70, -160.50),
     new google.maps.LatLng(68.85, -55.90)
   );

            // Listen for the dragend event
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
                if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

                // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

                var c = map.getCenter(),
         x = c.lng(),
         y = c.lat(),
         maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
         maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
         minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
         minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

                if (x < minX) x = minX;
                if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
                if (y < minY) y = minY;
                if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
            });

            // Limit the zoom level
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
                if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
            });


        }
```

Comment: What is "codeAddress()"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geocoding is asynchronous as is the getJSON call.  You start using the map variable before it is defined and initialized.

What is happening:

1. your code does a JSON request to the server
2. your code sets up the map drag event listener (map is undefined)
3. the server returns the JSON result, and does the all the geocoder calls
4. a geocode result comes back from the google server and initializes the map.
5. additional geocoder results come back from the server, each recreates and re-initializes the map

   ```
   var geocoder, infoBubble;
   var map;
   //var mgr;

   function initialize() {
       var minZoomLevel = 4;
       var zooms = 7;
       geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
       $.getJSON('/Dashboard/LoadAddress', function Geocode(address) {

           // ??? do you really want to create a new map for each address?
           $.each(address, function () {
               var currValAddress = this["AddressLine1"];
               geocoder.geocode({ 'address': currValAddress }, function (results, status) {
                 if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                         zoom: minZoomLevel,
                         center: currValAddress,
                         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                   })

                   // Bounds for North America
                   var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                     new google.maps.LatLng(15.70, -160.50),
                     new google.maps.LatLng(68.85, -55.90)
                   );

                   // Listen for the dragend event
                   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
                     if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;
                     // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

                     var c = map.getCenter(),

                     x = c.lng(),
                     y = c.lat(),
                     maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
                     maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
                     minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
                     minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

                     if (x < minX) x = minX;
                     if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
                     if (y < minY) y = minY;
                     if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

                     map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
                   });

                   // Limit the zoom level
                   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
                     if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
                   });

                 }
                 else {
                   alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                 }
               })
           });
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: sir. . I only get 1 set of data on GetJson so it will only create 1 Map . . But when i copy this set of codes the same error shows :(